# Move mouse pointer between screens that are not "touching" in display manager

Tags: windows

[image: Monitor setup]

Is there a way to allow the mouse pointer to move between screen 2 and 3.
I have this setup so that the pointer appears in the correct spot on screen 2 and 3 when moved from screen 1, but then I cant move it directly from screen 2 and 3.
I want to skip or ignore the space between the monitors.

Comment: To my knowledge this does not exists because this is the perfect way to lose your mouse cursor in the void or if it were to teleport between screens, constantly needing to pick up your mouse. Most people place the screens next to eachother if they want this.